# private method as trailing return type (decltype)

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype, trailing-return-type

When I am trying to use `decltype()` on a private method function I get the error that the private method `error: 'm1' has not been declared in this scope`

```
#include <stdint.h>

class C
{
public:
    C()=default;
    ~C()=default;

    auto masterMethod(int opMode) ->decltype(m1())
    {
        switch(opMode)
        {
        case 1:
                return m1(); break;
        case 2:
                return m2(); break;
        default:
                return m1(); break;
        }
    }
private:
    int m1() {return 1;}
    int m2() {return 2;}
};
```

Now my question is, why the compiler does not lookup in the private section of the class, because removing the trailing return type or putting the private section on top of `masterMethod` solves the problem (`decltype(auto)` [in case C++14 is allowed] would be also correct with its automatic return type deduction).

Furthermore, is it bad behaviour when removing the `decltype(m1())`when `m1()` and `m2()` have the same return-type, as this would do it for me too?

Comment: @Tyker One of those is from the `switch` statement.  I've edited the post to fix the indentation.

Comment: I dont understand your "Furthermore...". If `m1` and `m2` have different return types that cannot be converted into each other, then also `auto` wont help

Comment: @user463035818 but in my case, `m1`and `m2`have the same return-type, otherwise this would be - as you have written - wrong anyway

Comment: Interesting question: _"...The potential scope of a name declared in a class begins at the point of declaration and includes the rest of the class body and __all function bodies__ (even if defined outside the class definition or __before the declaration__ of the name), ..."_ from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope  I guess trailing return type is not part of function-body.  Suggest adding [language-lawyer] .

Comment: Note: this has nothing to do with `private`.

Comment: If we make `masterMethod()` a template, GCC complains: `error: there are no arguments to 'm1' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'm1' must be available`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is unrelated to both `private` and trailing return types.

The problem here is that while all declared names in a class are in scope in the *bodies* of its member functions, the trailing type is not part of the function body - it's part of the prototype.

Here is a much smaller example of the same problem:

```
struct A
{
    T f();
    using T = int;
};
```

And g++ says

```
error: 'T' does not name a type
```

But this is fine:

```
struct A
{
    using T = int;
    T f();
};
```

The only solution is to change the order of declaration.

Comment: Doesn't #1 [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#:scope,class) contradict that?

Comment: @SombreroChicken No, this is not a "complete-class context".

Comment: @SombreroChicken It does not because it only exists in the classes complete contect: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#6